# How to split a string into two parts when only knowing one part?

Tags: string, split

Hello I'm looking for a way to split a string into two parts when only knowing one part. To clarify there is NO separator to determine where to split the string on.

After splitting the string it should be possible to recognize if the resulting part is the left or right part of the string.

Consider the following use case scenario (a very simple string, JS syntax):

```js
const subject = 'foobar';
const known = 'foo';
const [left, right] = splitBySegment(subject, known);

console.log(left, right); // foo bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp (JS syntax):

```js
function splitBySegment(subject, known) {
    const escapeRegExp = new RegExp('[\\^$.*+?()[]{}|]', 'g');
    const knownEscaped = known.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&');

    const splitRegExp = new RegExp(
        '^' +
            `(?:${knownEscaped}|[A-Z]+(?=${knownEscaped}))` + // left
            '|' +
            `(?:${knownEscaped}|(?!${knownEscaped})[A-Z]+)` + // right
            '$',
        'g',
    );
    return subject.match(splitRegExp);
}
```